# Scala - create a generic type taking another generic type

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I'm refactoring a Java interface which defines all the concrete types inside the interface (the types that the methods are receiving and returning). I don't want to enforce those type constraints and wish to keep the interface generic, the input and output value types should themselves be generic. Some of the methods in the interface are recursive in the sense that they return generic type defined inside a different generic type defining the trait itself. I need to reference the generic types inside the trait.

For instance:

```
trait Product[ID,GROUP] {
  def getProductId : ID // the product ID could be an Int,String, or some other type
  def getGroup : GROUP
}

// define a generic reader for the generic products
trait Reader[Key,Prod <: Product[What should I write here?] {
  def getProduct(key: Key) : Product
  def getProductsInGroup(group : Prod.getGroupType) : Seq[Prod] << How do I reference the Prod.GROUP type parameter?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another type parameter:

```
 trait Reader[Key, Group, Prod <: Product[Key, Group]] {
     def getProduct(key: Key): Prod
     def getProductIdsInGroup(group: Group): Seq[Prod]
 }
```

For the record, I am not sure what it is you don't like about inner type definitions as an alternative BTW. Don't know what "constraints" you are talking about.

```
 trait Product { 
   type Id
   type Group
 }

 trait Reader[Prod <: Product] {
    def getProduct(key: Prod#Id) 
    def getProductIdsInGroup(group: Prod#Group): Seq[Prod]
 }
```

Comment: What i mean is that I don't want the trait to have something like "getProductsFromGroup(groupId : Int) : Seq(Prod)" , (Don't want to hard code 'Int' - I want the type of the group to be taken from the product's groupd type) All of types in the traits are defined in generic terms and are defined by the concrete implenentations

Comment: Im not familiar with the "type" syntax for a generic Product, How would I go about using it?

Comment: How about copy and paste the snippet I posted? ;)